# What is a good method Recommender System for my dataset?

Tags: php

I have the following dataset:
Dataset Application:
3500 user review for 70 applications (50 user review / application)
divided into 4 categories
I also have made scoring for each application based on the sentiment classification

Users Dataset:
user with a list of applications that are already installed on the device's (there are 5-10 users)

My question:
what method should Recommender System that I created, which can produce a good level of accuracy?

Thank You
Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Naive Bayes Classifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) algorithm. There are implementations in many languages.